# I always have to boot windows trough the BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios

**My problem**

Every time I boot my Windows 10 laptop, it get's stuck in a BIOS loop. In this loop, the BIOS apparently can't find my hard drive, so it reboots the system, loads up the BIOS again and fails to find the hard drive again. This goes on infinitely.

**My workaround**

It's not until I hold down "ESC" during the cycle to get into the BIOS menu, that I can manually choose the hard drive I wish to boot. The hard drive is shown in the BIOS's boot override/priority menu, it's also the only boot option recognized, so it isn't like an other device is taking priority. The correct drive is the **only** item in that list. So naturally I pick that drive to "override" the boot with, which works every time.

**What I've tried**

Updating the bios didn't change result, so I'm thinking the fault might be on the hard drive or windows 10 side. If I restart my laptop trough windows 10, the system does boot normally, so it doesn't get stuck in the loop.
After the latest windows 10 update the problem still continues.

Is there a way or tool to fix my BIOS or windows 10 installation to always be recognized as the preferred boot system?

Note that the drive is already my preferred boot option in the BIOS (of course) , it's just ignoring the setting.

Comment: How old is the motherboard? Maybe the CMOS battery is depleted and the motherboard can't remember CMOS settings.

Comment: Is there a BIOS option to delay hardware detection? My guess: your HDD (or whatever, for some reason) may need more time to initialize. When you get into the menu you give it the time it needs.

Comment: @styrofoamfly It's a guess, but I'd say about 4 years at least. I'll look into it, but I doubt I can reach wherever the battery is located since it's a laptop. It might be interesting to note that I don't have the problem if I turn off the laptop and boot it right after that. It seems like the problem only occurs if the system is off for too long. So it might be possible that whatever data is holding my preferences, loses it after being turned off for a while.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I would say my system is on the fast side. The drive I'm talking about is an SSD drive.

Comment: I'm not saying your SSD is slow. I'm saying some (malfunctioning?) hardware may initialize itself too slow.